# multi culture in c#

Tags: c#, culture

i have error in my multi culture project

error message:

Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between 03/21/0622 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 12/31/9999 23:59:59 (Gregorian date), inclusive.
Parameter name: time

my program stack :

```
  at System.Globalization.PersianCalendar.CheckTicksRange(Int64 ticks)
   at System.Globalization.PersianCalendar.GetDatePart(Int64 ticks, Int32 part)
   at System.Globalization.PersianCalendar.GetYear(DateTime time)
   at System.DateTimeFormat.FormatCustomized(DateTime dateTime, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, TimeSpan offset)
   at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, TimeSpan offset)
   at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
   at System.DateTime.ToString()
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDateTimePickerCalendar.maskBox_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMaskedEditBoxElement.CallValueChanged(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.MaskDateTimeProvider.Validate(String stringValue)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMaskedEditBoxElement.set_Text(String value)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDateTimePicker.set_Text(String value)
```

Comment: What is the value of `time`? Have you already tried to set a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: line is in PersianCalendar in .net frame work class

Comment: I would readily assume that Telerik hasn't debugged their control to work with a Persian calendar.  They no doubt implicitly assume that a single digit can be converted to a year.  Works in the Georgian calendar, kaboom in the Persian calendar.  You'll need their support to get past this hump.